# PHP - Relative paths to included and required files

Tags: php

Well, i am working with a framework that is composed of a somewhat complex file and directory structure.
in my application, i just need to require a file, like so:

```
require "framework/mainfile.php";
```

inside mainfile, it is including other files, like:

```
include "framework/classes/class1.php";
....
```

and inside some class files it is including other files in the same way;

what i need is to change the location of the framework files and thus the relative path to the framework files in order to have something like

```
include "lib/framework/mainfile.php";
```

but i don't want to look in all the files and change the path in every one of them because i would always have to be doing it again when i change to a new version of the framework.
Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use
 `set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath('Your/updated/path'),
    get_include_path(),
));`
 so your current include paths will not be effected 
and you will not need to make change in all files

Answer (score 1):

You can use `__DIR__` to get the absolute path of the directory the current script is in. You can then use:

```
include __DIR__ . '/classes/class1.php';
```

Comment: yes, but i don't want to have to change the files of the framework.

Comment: The way I understand this solves your problem, please test it.

Comment: those includes are in the framework files. I know that works, but i stated that i don't want to change the framework files

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. You should then try the Example #2 here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php

Comment: yes, that's it. Can you please edit your answer with a paste of that code so i can accept your answer as the correct one? thanks